# Using ng-pattern does not work from controller or JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller, ng-pattern

I have this code which will only accept 6 digit numeric:

```
<input
   ng-pattern="{{widget.regex}}" 
   name="{{widget.id}}">
{{widget.regex}}

<span ng-if="(myForm[item.id].$touched === true && myForm[item.id].$valid === false)" class="help-block">
    <div ng-message="pattern">Enter 6 digit ID</div>
</span>
```

and the regex value is being set from JSON file like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "customerID",
      "label": "Enter ID",
      "required": "yes",
      "regex": "/^[0-9]{6,6}$/i"
    },
    {
      "id": "customerEmail",
      "label": "Email",
      "required": "yes"
    }
  ]
},
```

and here's the output:

[image]

Now the problem is, if I keyin 6 digit numeric in the ID field, the error message wont go away. Any number I enter will not make it work. However if I hardcoded the regex to `ng-pattern` attribute like this:

```
<input
   ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{6,6}$/i" 
   name="{{widget.id}}">
{{widget.regex}}

<span ng-if="(myForm[item.id].$touched === true && myForm[item.id].$valid === false)" class="help-block">
    <div ng-message="pattern">Enter 6 digit ID</div>
</span>
```

[image]

It will work! The error message will go away. I also tested it from controller like this:

```
vm.regex = new RegExp('/^[0-9]{6,6}$/i');
```

and it does not worked too. Anyone know what is the problem? Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegExp constructor can be expressed in two ways:

```
new RegExp('ab+c', 'i');   //string notation
new RegExp(/ab+c/i);   //literal regex notation
```

Notice how the string notation does not have the / character, but the literal notation does.

ng-pattern automatically converts the string input to literal notation if the / characters are included. If it detects a string without enclosing / characters, it wraps it in ^ and $ characters. E.g. `"abc"` will be converted to `new RegExp('^abc$')` but `"/abc/i"` will evaluate to `new RegExp(/abc/i)`.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Comment: Changing `"regex": "/^[0-9]{6,6}$/i"` to `"regex": "[0-9]{6,6}"` solved the problem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: but why does hardcoding the regex to `ng-pattern` does worked though? Isn't it will messed up my regex from `/^[0-9]{6,6}$/i` to `^/^[0-9]{6,6}$/i$`?

Comment: From the ng-pattern docs: If the expression evaluates to a RegExp object, then this is used directly. So angular is smart enough to know `ng-pattern = "/^[0-9]{6,6}$/i"` will convert directly to `new RegExp(/^[0-9]{6,6}$/i)`. Answer has been edited to reflect this.